# Flask Paginate and Current_user

Tags: python-3.x, flask

i need help with my code, i can't see paginated clients of the current_user in session
code view:

```
@views.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'], defaults={"page": 1}) 
@views.route('/<int:page>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home(page):
    client = Client.query.paginate(page=page,per_page=3,error_out=False)

    return render_template("home.html", user=current_user, client=client)
```

code models:

```
class Client(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(150)) 
    email = db.Column(db.String(150))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150)) 
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    clients = db.relationship('Client')
```

code html:

```
{% for client in user.clients.items %}
```

With this code doesn't show me nothing, if i change code of html for:

```
{% for client in client.items %}
```

It show me all clients of all users, and i want see only clients from current_user, need help please :(

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need to filter the query in the route to only get clients that belong to the current user you can do this by:

```
client = Client.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).paginate(page=page,per_page=3,error_out=False)
```

I have not tested this so could be some spelling mistakes

Comment: Thanks a ton!! It was driving me crazy. Now i can continue